# What is a solution to this error TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime

can please anyone helps me with my code?
this is the error that I got
I just don't get it on how did I get this error:

```
CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(CurrentDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date
```

Full code:

```py
import datetime

CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
print(CurrentDate)

Run4Start = str(CurrentDate) + " 16:00"
Run4End = str(CurrentDate) + " 20:00"
Run4Start = datetime.datetime.strptime(Run4Start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Run4End = datetime.datetime.strptime(Run4End, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print("RUN4 :", CurrentDate )
print(Run4Start, Run4End)


CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(CurrentDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print(CurrentDate)

if CurrentDate >= Run4Start and CurrentDate <= Run4End:
    print("Hit")
else:
    print("Miss!")
```

Comment: That line should be using `strftime`, not `strptime`.

Comment: `strptime` is for parsing a string into a datetime, `strftime` is for formatting a datetime as a string.

Comment: Even after changing this to `strftime` it throws an error. Is the second `CurrentDate` meant to be `datetime.datetime.now()`?

Comment: @Barmar: Except the very next thing done is to compare it to a parsed `datetime`, so `strftime` is logically wrong, even if it would work for that call. They don't really need to parse or format a thing here, they don't need *dates* at all, the ultimate logic is just a check if the current time of day is in a specific range.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point. I didn't read past `print(CurrentDate)`. He should use a different variable for that.

Comment: `RUN4 : 2020-01-16 19:15:44.431774
1900-01-01 23:00:00 1900-01-01 00:00:00
Miss!`........this the output that i want to have but the date of the this out is  "1900-01-01 i want to change that date to the current date

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(CurrentDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

`CurrentDate` is *already* a `datetime.date` object, created above:

```
CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

and never changed to anything else. So you don't need to parse it, it's already "parsed". Just remove the line attempting to parse it.

That said, it's just a `date`, and you're comparing it to `datetime`s on a specific day; whether or not it works, it won't do what you're probably trying to do (determine if the current time is between 1600 and 2000). You don't need string parsing to do that at all; your entire block of code testing for a hit vs. miss could simplify to:

```
if datetime.time(16) <= datetime.datetime.now().time() <= datetime.time(20):
    print("Hit")
else:
    print("Miss!")
```

since you only care about the time component, not the date component at all.

Comment: i want also the date to be accurate also

Comment: `RUN4 : 2020-01-16 19:22:57.428023
1900-01-01 23:00:00 1900-01-01 00:00:00
Miss!` this the output my old code but i notice the date was wrong

Comment: @Sanuba_Beech: Your date, in all three cases, came from the same call to `datetime.datetime.now()`. If it's 2020-01-16 in one, it's 2020-01-16 in the other two that were parsed from it. So the date really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Sanuba_Beech: That's not the output your existing code would produce. I don't know where you got that, but it's not what you provided. We can't diagnose bugs in code we can't see (not reliably anyway).

Comment: sorry i dont get it because maybe i just watching youtube but this my old code and runs smooth but it always miss because of the date `import datetime

CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.now()

Run4Start = "23:00"
Run4End = "00:00"
Run4Start = datetime.datetime.strptime(Run4Start, "%H:%M")
Run4End = datetime.datetime.strptime(Run4End, "%H:%M")
print("RUN4 :", CurrentDate )
print(Run4Start, Run4End)

if CurrentDate >= Run4Start and CurrentDate <= Run4End:
    print("Hit")
else:
    print("Miss!")` this is my old code if you run it u will notice  that the date was wrong

Comment: @Sanuba_Beech: The date was wrong because you didn't parse a date at all. But **you don't need to compare dates**. Your new code is getting the *current* date, then checking if the *current* date and time falls between 1600 and 2000 on the *current* date. Notice how it's always the same (current) date? You don't need to test it. The code I provided simply tests that the *current* time of day falls between 1600 and 2000; the current day is definitely today, we don't really need to confirm that.

Comment: `Run4Start = datetime.datetime.strftime(Run4Start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object`  so this error is not what should i focus on?

Comment: @Sanuba_Beech: That's not from *any* of the code you've provided, in either the question or the comments. You keep introducing new code that involves constantly formatting and/or parsing `datetime`s (or components thereof), and none of which is necessary for the actual logic of your code (checking if the current time falls within a given range). I can't help you when the question changes every minute, the code is incomplete and/or constantly in flux, and you insist on using techniques that have nothing to do with solving your problem.

Comment: `import datetime
CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
print(CurrentDate)
Run4Start = str(CurrentDate) + " 16:00"
Run4End = str(CurrentDate) + " 20:00"
Run4Start = datetime.datetime.strftime(Run4Start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Run4End = datetime.datetime.strftime(Run4End, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
print("RUN4 :", CurrentDate )
print(Run4Start, Run4End)
CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.strftime(CurrentDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
if datetime.time() <= datetime.datetime.now().time() <= datetime.time():
    print("Hit")
else:
    print("Miss!")` this the code im working on right now

Comment: i really am sorry if i confuse you so much